# Accessing Draw Tools objects with notebook commands

Tags: graphics, drawing

In a notebook I would like to be able to access and modify the properties of draw tools objects after I've drawn them on a graph by hand.

For example, if make a plot and, with draw tools, make a circle, is it possible now to access the circle Graphics object and its properties with commands in the notebook?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is surely possible because the graphics created with the *Drawing Tools* is just a normal `Graphics` object. Let me give you an example. I made a new drawing and assigned it to a variable:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I can work with `img` in the same way I would do it with other graphics. For instance you could look at the code you have created:

```
InputForm[img]
(* Graphics[{Circle[{0.9027777777777779, 0.1972222222222222}, 
   {0.26527777777777783, 0.13611111111111107}], 
  {EdgeForm[{GrayLevel[0.], Opacity[1.], AbsoluteThickness[1]}], 
   FaceForm[Hue[0.5, 1., 1.]], 
   Style[Rectangle[{0.17222222222222228, 0.8083333333333333}, 
     {0.6375000000000002, 0.41388888888888875}], 
    RectangleBoxOptions -> {RoundingRadius -> 0}]}}, 
 ContentSelectable -> True, ImagePadding -> {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.}}, 
 ImageSize -> {480, 360}, PlotRange -> {{0., 1.3333333333333335}, 
  {0., 1.}}, PlotRangePadding -> Automatic] *)
```

And of course you can manipulate everything for instance by replace parts of the graphics:

```
img /. Circle[pt_, r_] :> {FaceForm[Red], Disk[pt, r]}
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for the quick response.  Nice example.  It seems rather obvious now.